# Loading Data in Background, Updating Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I am using an ArrayAdapter to display a list of items, and I have an AsyncTask thread that loads these items via HttpURLConnection. I want this list of items to be the first thing the user sees on launching the app. I know that it is bad practice to have the app wait on launch for this load to complete, which is why I made the load an AsyncTask. I have local data stored in SharedPreferences which displays in the meantime.

Unfortunately I can't modify the adapter directly from within the AsyncTask.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.`

I suppose I just need a signal to notify the UI thread that the background task is done; I can modify my code to load the data in another data structure that is not the Adapter, and then the UI thread can add it to the Adapter once it knows the task is complete. I don't know how to do this though without waiting for AsyncTask to complete, which is the same as if I was waiting for the data to load in the main UI thread.

How should I go about this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        ...
        LoadAnnouncementDataFromAPI announcementAPIQuery = new LoadAnnouncementDataFromAPI();
        announcementAPIQuery.execute();
        ...
    }

    ...

    private class LoadAnnouncementDataFromAPI extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String announcementAPI = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/announcements";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(announcementAPI);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String queryResponse) {
            if (queryResponse != null && !queryResponse.equals("")) {
                try {
                    JSONArray apiResponse = new JSONArray(queryResponse);
                    for (int i = 0; i < apiResponse.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject announcementJSON = apiResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (!announcementJSON.getString("id").equals("")) {
                            mAnnouncementAdapter.items.add(new AnnouncementBlock(announcementJSON));
                        }
                    }
                    mAnnouncementAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use publishProgress

Comment: I don't understand why it is wondering you that you should wait until you will fetch data before showing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that just by adding a listener to your asynTask. When you get your callback make sure the updating code runs on the UI thread.

**Some code**

1 - The callback interface

```
interface OnAddListener {
    void onAdd (AnnouncementBlock announcementBlock);
}
```

2 - Alter your class

```
class LoadAnnouncementDataFromAPI extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    OnAddListener listener;

    public void setOnAddListener(OnAddListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    LoadAnnouncementDataFromAPI(OnAddListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        // Or may be pass it to the constructor...
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Your logic
        // And then!
        if(listener!=null){
            listener.onAdd(new AnnouncementBlock(announcementJSON));
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

3 - You could get your callbacks form the activity. I tend to like the approach where the activity is implementing the interface directly (to avoid the `final` keyword probably) but you could do it otherwise.

```
// Notice that the activity is implementing the OnAddListener interface.
class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnAddListener {

    // ... Some logic life cycle callbacks

    // I suppose you're doing something similar
    private void startUpdating(){
        mLoadAnnouncementDataFromAPI.setListener(this); // set the listener.
    }

    // Your callback.
    @Override
    public void onAdd(final AnnouncementBlock announcementBlock) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Now you're sure it's running in the UI thread ;)
                mAnnouncementAdapter.items.onAdd(announcementBlock);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a function setListAdapter where you create a new instance of your adapter passing the new data as bellow:

```
public void setListAdapter (AnnouncementBlock listdata)   
    {
        If (listAdapter != null){
           listAdapter = null;
        }
     listAdapter = new MyListAdapter (listdata);
}
```

And call thus metho in your postExecute